# Ubuntu MATE 14.04 LTSP Problems

Tags: 14.04, networking, virtualbox, mate, ltsp

I've come across a problem where I have gone through a read-me verbatim, and although it works fine, every time I reboot my system (Virtualbox in this matter), the IP address changes even though I have it set on static. I don't know where to go to at this point. Another, but minor, problem is that the clients do not have internet, but I won't touch on that until the main problem is resolved.

Said read-me: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-to-install-pnp-ltsp-on-ubuntu-mate-14-04-lts/566/15

**ANY** help would be amazing.

Comment: Can you paste your `/etc/network/interfaces` config file? I have had success when manually configuring that file to use a static ip. Also, post a response to your referenced link. The author is quite speedy at replying.

Comment: @awei I gave up on MATE and moved on to just using regular Ubuntu. I've used up my three replies on that page and it was no help to be honest.

Comment: well lemme know if you need some specific help w/ ltsp. I've been struggling through it myself for the past month and have picked up a few things along the way. feel free to PM me.

Comment: Thanks. :) I've moved on from MATE to just using base Ubuntu because MATE bothered me so much.

Comment: Wow i just realized I just said the exact same thing, haha, no coffee today

Comment: Modifying /etc/network/interfaces as shown above was sufficient for me, I didn't have to edit resolvconf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will set a static ip that network manager will respect.  I have copied this from personal ubuntu 14.04 ltsp install instructions so you may not need some of it.  I tried to modify the addresses based off your information in the linked questions.  I substituted the local nameserver IP addresses with Google's.  Modify as needed.  I also set an example domain search.

```
#
# set static ip
#
sudo -i
echo "" >> /etc/network/interfaces
echo "" >> /etc/network/interfaces
echo "auto eth0" >> /etc/network/interfaces
echo "iface eth0 inet static" >> /etc/network/interfaces
echo "    address 192.168.1.2" >> /etc/network/interfaces
echo "    netmask 255.255.255.0" >> /etc/network/interfaces
echo "    gateway 192.168.1.1" >> /etc/network/interfaces
echo "    dns-search internal.example.com" >> /etc/network/interfaces
echo "    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4" >> /etc/network/interfaces
echo "" >> /etc/network/interfaces
echo "" >> /etc/network/interfaces
echo "" >> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
echo "nameserver 8.8.4.4" >> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
echo "" >> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
resolvconf -u
reboot
exit
```

You can also make use of the DNS_SERVER variable in the `lts.conf` file. For example,

```
[Default]
... snip ...
DNS_SERVER="8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4"
... snip ...
```

instead of adjusting the network manager / dnsmasq configuration.